# Is it possible to restrict an application to only run on iPhone 4 and higher?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPad game and I'm attempting to port it to the iPhone, but it is very graphically heavy and I would rather not have to make an iPhone 4 and a non-Retina (iPhone 3GS, etc.) version for the game.

Is it possible to restrict the download to just the iPhone 4 users? If not does anyone have another suggestion for this?

Comment: My initial response to the screenshots of the app was that it should not be that graphically heavy. There are 3d games running flawlessly on the 3gs. Your game should be able to do that too.

Comment: @MrThys you mean it should NOT be that graphically heavy.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10). To limit to just the iPhone 4 and 4S you could ask for the `front-facing-camera` capability. But have a look through the capabilities as another might suit you better. Maybe `opengles-2` capability if your game is using OpenGL then that might be the exact one you want?